# Using SystemColors dynamically in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like my application to handle High Contrast themes in Windows. To replicate the issue, first switch to a High Contrast theme. Then make a simple WPF application with this code in xaml:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox>A checkbox</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}">ControlTextBrushKey</CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

It will look like this in the UI

[image]

For some reason, ControlTextBrushKey always resolves to #FFFFFFFF regardless of what theme I am on. What am I missing? Shouldn't it be green too?

Comment: Is it same if you use TextElement.Foreground?

Comment: replace it with Foreground. Literally.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is my observation:

**Windows 7:** If `High Contrast #2` with `Aero Theme` is selected, ControlTextBrushKey is green as expected. But if `High Contrast #1` with `Aero Theme` is selected, ControlTextBrushKey returns White. Below is the screen shot having `High Contrast #2` with `Aero Theme`

[image]

**Windows 8:** Regardless of the high contrast (`High Contrast #1` or `High Contrast #2`) with default theme, `ControlTextBrushKey` always returns `#FFFFFFFF`

Below are the tables for `High Contrast #1` & `High Contrast #2` taken from [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference.aspx) and it works on Windows 7 according to this table. Search for `ControlTextBrush`

**High Contrast #1**

[image: High Contrast #1]

**High Contrast #2:**

[image: High Contrast #2]

Comment: Indeed, I am using Windows 8 in this case. So in Windows 8 there is no way to link to the green ControlTextBrush?

Comment: This chart was helpful - http://www.quppa.net/syscol/ - but it doesn't explain why the default checkbox would turn green and how to match it. Maybe it is WindowText? Not ControlText?

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. I should have been using WindowText.